# Два контекста содержат одинаковые имена сущностей

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net, entity

Интересует вопрос по Entity Framework. Имею две базы данных и в них встречаются таблицы с одинаковыми именами.

Как сделать, чтобы в пределах одного проекта работать с таблицами обоих БД? Именно с теми таблицами, у которых имена совпадают

[image: Автогенерированный код]

[image: Исключение]

//1 контекст

```
public partial class UGTU_TESTEntities : DbContext
{
    public UGTU_TESTEntities()
        : base("name=UGTU_TESTEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Gorod> Gorod { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Raion> Raion { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Region> Region { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Strana> Strana { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Street> Street { get; set; }
}
```

//2 контекст

```
public partial class UGTUTestForAddressEntities : DbContext
{
    public UGTUTestForAddressEntities()
        : base("name=UGTUTestForAddressEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Gorod> Gorod { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Raion> Raion { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Region> Region { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Strana> Strana { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Street> Street { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Address> Address { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Okrug> Okrug { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Zaved_stud> Zaved_stud { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AddressCZS> AddressCZS { get; set; }
}
```

> Необработанное исключение типа
>   "System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException" в EntityFramework.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Указанная схема недопустима. Ошибки:
>
> Сопоставление типа CLR с EDM-типом является неоднозначным, поскольку
>   несколько типов CLR соответствуют типу модели EDM "Raion". Предыдущий
>   найденный тип CLR "IntegrationAddress.UGTU_TEST.Raion". Найден тип CLR
>   "IntegrationAddress.UGTU.Raion".
>
> Сопоставление типа CLR с EDM-типом является неоднозначным, поскольку
>   несколько типов CLR соответствуют типу модели EDM "Strana". Предыдущий
>   найденный тип CLR "IntegrationAddress.UGTU_TEST.Strana". Найден тип
>   CLR "IntegrationAddress.UGTU.Strana".

Исключение вылезает при выполнении данного кода:

```
        using (var dbReal = new IntegrationAddress.UGTU.UGTUTestForAddressEntities())
        {
            var stranas = dbReal.Strana.ToList();
            var regs = dbReal.Region.ToList();
            var areas = dbReal.Raion.ToList();
            var towns = dbReal.Gorod.ToList();
            var streets = dbReal.Street.ToList();
            var ads = dbReal.Address.ToList();
            var adsCz = dbReal.AddressCZS.ToList();
            var zavs = dbReal.Zaved_stud.ToList();
            var oks = dbReal.Okrug.ToList();
        }

        using (var dbTest = new IntegrationAddress.UGTU_TEST.UGTU_TESTEntities())
        {
            var stranas = dbTest.Strana.ToList();
            var regs = dbTest.Region.ToList();
            var areas = dbTest.Raion.ToList();
            var towns = dbTest.Gorod.ToList();
            var streets = dbTest.Street.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Comment: проблема в том что когда в контекстах однаруживаются 2 сущности с одинаковыми названиями, вылетает исключение, хотя контексты разные

Comment: *Какое* исключение?

Comment: Необработанное исключение типа "System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException" в EntityFramework.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Не удалось загрузить указанный ресурс метаданных.

Comment: Приведите пример кода программы (не весь, а достаточный для того чтобы исключение произошло), а также исключение полностью!

Comment: код не привел, так как он автосгенерированный

Comment: На ваших скриншотах ничего не видно. Приведите код, тут нет телепатов.

Comment: так сойдет? или весь проект опубликовать?

Comment: Зачем вы пишите имена типов в транслите? Если уж занимаетесь подобным, то почему не на кириллице? C# поддерживает исходники в Unicode.

Comment: потому что в БД так, это автосгенерированный код

Comment: Переименуйте свои классы любыми именами, но только пометьте атрибутом `[Table("TableNameIdDBO")]`

Answer (score 0):

Это известная проблема, которая существует by Design в EF6 для edmx схем. Одним из решений является правка edmx схемы с явным указанием пространства имён

```
<ConceptualModels>
    <Schema Namespace="ConsoleApplication33" 
        Alias="Self" 
        annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false"
        xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" 
        xmlns:customannotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2013/11/edm/customannotation" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
    <EntityType Name="Person" 
        customannotation:ClrType="MyApp.Person, MyApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
        <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="Id" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
        <Property Name="Name" Type="String" MaxLength="Max" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
    </EntityType>
    <EntityContainer Name="Town" customannotation:UseClrTypes="true">
        <EntitySet Name="People" EntityType="Self.Person" />
    </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
</ConceptualModels>
```

https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/issues/362